# Stable uasort - why is the order being reversed?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm using uasort to sort an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
  [2] => 0
  [3] => 0
  [4] => 0
)
```

I'm trying to sort by value, maintaining key association. In addition, I need to keep the original order if the values are the same.

So I'm doing the following:

```
uasort($arr, array($this, 'mysort'));

function mysort($a, $b){
  if($a == $b){
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a < $b) ? -1:1;
}
```

However, this gives the resulting array:

```
Array
(
  [4] => 0
  [3] => 0
  [2] => 0
)
```

Why is the array being effectively reversed?

Comment: PHP 5.x < reverses the order. PHP 7 behaves as expected. I described the issue [here](https://github.com/mblarsen/arrgh#php5-vs-php7) and [these are the values](https://github.com/mblarsen/arrgh/blob/master/src/Arrgh.php#L10) I return for when elements are equal for PHP 5.x and 7. I added a function that checks the version and returns the correct integer accordingly. Otherwise you a screwed if you code has to run on both versions. [Tests running on 5+7](https://travis-ci.org/mblarsen/arrgh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uasort` is *not* a stable sort, that is, it doesn't maintain the order of equal values.

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)'s notes section contains a `stable_uasort`.

Comment: Thanks for reading the manual for me! I had skimmed past that comment assuming it was for multi-dimensional arrays. (And that my return 0 would leave the order untouched when the values were the same.)

Comment: The PHP manual is quite poorly documented, missing many corner cases and details, it's worth checking that section ;)